# What does the `as` command do in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command

I've seen it many times but never understood what the `as` command does in Python 3.x. Can you explain it in plain English?

Comment: It's a reserved keyword, at least in py2.6+.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a command per se, it's a keyword used as part of the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

The object after  `as` gets assigned the result of the expression handled by the `with` context manager.

Another use is to rename an imported module:

```
import numpy as np
```

so you can use the name `np` instead of `numpy` from now on.

The third use is to give you access to an `Exception` object:

```
try:
    f = open("foo")
except IOError as exc:
    # Now you can access the Exception for more detailed analysis
```

Comment: thanks but i don't know what do the `with` statement do. Can you explain?

Comment: I can't find any technical reference for the "as" statement in the official Python docs. Anyone know of one?

Comment: @BrianHVB: Since it isn't a "standalone" keyword, you need to look at the documentation of `with`, `try/except` and `import`

Answer (score 5):

It is a keyword used for object naming in several cases.

```
from some_module import something as some_alias
# `some_alias` is `some_module.something`

with open("filename") as f:
    # `f` is the file object `open("filename")` returned

try:
    Nonsense!
except Exception as e:
    # `e` is the Exception thrown
```

Comment: It's not really a renaming in the second and third case, is it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, I think it's just naming.

Comment: So what would the name have been before the "renaming"?

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're the only one who mentioned **re**naming. Kabie just said it was about naming.